# Preciso mudar o botão onclick para angular.js

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, mysqli

Boa noite. Estou usando a paginação do Bootstrap com Angular.js .
Consigo pegar os dados do banco e listar, ficou bonito, etc... do jeito que eu precisava.

Porém, preciso abrir uma janela modal e isso funcionava quando eu estava usando as funções javascript que conheço como o OnClick.

Mas usando a paginação com angular, minha função onclick não funciona.
Abaixo segue o link e documentação da paginação com Angula.js:

```
http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/
```

Tenho a seguinte função a ser chamada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function detalhes(id) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $("#conteudoModal").load('verProduto.php?id=' + id);
}
```

E na paginação, lista de produtos eu tenho o botão:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" onclick="detalhes({{data.id}})">+ Detalhes</button></td>
```

O problema está aqui:

```
onclick="detalhes({{data.id}})"
```

O id chega nesse formato: **{{data.id}}** , já usei aspas, +, . e nada rsrrsrsr Teria algum jeito de trabalhar melhor isso? Não entendo muito de Angular.js , apenas peguei ele e adaptei e ficou lindo...mas preciso do botão funcionando...

Conforme solicitado, segue o controller:

```
var app = angular.module('produtos', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    if(input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
}
});
app.controller('produtosCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('../html/paginacao/ajax/getProdutos.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

Poderiam me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Poderia postar o código do *controller* que está utilizando para manipular esse `data-id`?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, acrescentando o controller.

Comment: Tente trocar onclick para ng-click

Comment: @MarciaPereiraReis eu percebi que você está usando o módulo 'ui.bootstrap'. A sua função para abrir modal terá que ser alterada um pouco.

Você pode ver esse exemplo aqui: http://plnkr.co/edit/qpUwt2Ozj9thNR7IubFj

Comment: Obrigado pelo link @WédneyYuri ... me ajudou e resolveu meu problema. Tks

Comment: @WédneyYuri poste como resposta, links externos podem quebrar. Não somos um fórum de ajuda mas sim uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas. Por favor formule uma resposta.

Comment: Me parece que a dica do Wedney Yuri lhe ajudou, mas não era bem uma resposta direta ao problema, você pode responder a sua própria pergunta, isto pode vir a ajudar outros usuários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução:

```
$scope.detalhes = function (id) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $("#conteudoModal").load('verProduto.php?id=' + id);
};
```